# Error: "zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped"

Tags: r, plot

This is my first time posting here so I'll do my best; I'm trying to add error bars to a plot but I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In arrows(x0 = pen$l, y0 = pen$per - pen$error, x1 = pen$l,  ... :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
2: In arrows(x0 = pen$l, y0 = pen$per - pen$error, x1 = pen$l,  ... :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
3: In arrows(x0 = pen$l, y0 = pen$per - pen$error, x1 = pen$l,  ... :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
4: In arrows(x0 = pen$l, y0 = pen$per - pen$error, x1 = pen$l,  ... :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
5: In arrows(x0 = pen$l, y0 = pen$per - pen$error, x1 = pen$l,  ... :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
6: In arrows(x0 = pen$l, y0 = pen$per - pen$error, x1 = pen$l,  ... :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
7: In arrows(x0 = pen$l, y0 = pen$per - pen$error, x1 = pen$l,  ... :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
8: In arrows(x0 = pen$l, y0 = pen$per - pen$error, x1 = pen$l,  ... :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
9: In arrows(x0 = pen$l, y0 = pen$per - pen$error, x1 = pen$l,  ... :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
10: In arrows(x0 = pen$l, y0 = pen$per - pen$error, x1 = pen$l,  ... :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
11: In arrows(x0 = pen$l, y0 = pen$per - pen$error, x1 = pen$l,  ... :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
There were 22 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
pen=read.csv("datosalt.csv",header=T)
plot(pen$l,pen$per,pch=19)
arrows(x0=pen$l,y0=pen$per-pen$error,x1=pen$l,y1=pen$per-pen$error,code=3,length=0.02,angle=90)
```

And this is my dataframe (datosalt.csv):

```
per,error,l
0.78,0.06,15
1,0.05,25
1.21,0.06,35
1.37,0.07,45
1.49,0.03,55
1.62,0.03,65
1.62,0.03,65
1.74,0.03,75
1.88,0.06,85
1.88,0.06,85
1.96,0.08,95
```

There *should* be nothing wrong with them since the numbers in my dataframe make sense and the code was written by my proffesor, but it shows me those warnings and doesn't add the error bars I need. I haven't been able to find anything online since this seems to be a problem specific to each code, plus I'm pretty new to coding altogether, so if anyone can point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What plot package are you using? What values do your variables have (are they creating a "zero arrow")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, I think your issue is that you are using the same x0 and x1, and y0 and y1, meaning it's trying to draw an arrow between itself: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/arrows

However, if you change the second y1 from per-error to per+error, I think it solves your problem:

```
pen<- data.frame(per = c(0.78,1,1.21,1.37,1.49,1.62,1.62,1.74,1.88,1.88,1.96),
                 error = c(0.06,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.06,0.06,0.08),
                 l = c(15,25,35,45,55,65,65,75,85,85,95)
)
plot(pen$l,pen$per,pch=19)
arrows(x0=pen$l,y0=pen$per-pen$error,x1=pen$l,y1=pen$per+pen$error,code=3,length=0.02,angle=90)
```